# Infinite exponential sum doubt

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, logarithms, exponential-sum

Hello! I have a couple of doubts regarding a formula seen [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/23/01/0005/) :

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac {e^{kz}}{k}= -\log (1-e^{z}) /; Re(z)<0$$

1. What would happen if the real part of z Re(z) were equal to 0? Is there a formula for when Re(z)=0?
2. If the formula were

$$Im(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac {e^{kz}}{k})$$ 
being Im(z) the imaginary part of z, would it be equal to 
$$Im(-\log (1-e^{z}))$$
without mattering Re(z)?

Thanks!

Comment: it is well-known that for $|s| < 1$ : $\frac{1}{1-s} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty s^k$, hence integrating both sides $-\ln(1-s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k}$, and by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem when the RHS converges, the equality stays true, i.e. for $|s| = 1, s \ne 1$

Comment: As an example of what can happen if $z$ is pure imaginary, note that $z=0$ gives the harmonic series which is divergent whereas $z=i\pi$ gives the alternating harmonic series which is convergent.

Comment: (note how https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem applied to $G(z)$ is related to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series of $f(t) = G(e^{i t})$ )

Comment: So would the answer to the 2nd question be Yes?